# Как отключить клиента от сервера TCP

Tags: c#, сервер, клиент-сервер, tcp

Имеется клиент-серверное приложение.

Клиент:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace Client
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread receiveThread;
    static string userName = null;
    static TcpClient client;
    static NetworkStream stream;
    private const string host = "127.0.0.1";
    private const int port = 8888;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        chatTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;

    }

    private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (userNameTextBox.TextLength <= 2)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Минимальная длина имени 3 символа.");
        }
        else
        {
            userName = userNameTextBox.Text;
            client = new TcpClient();
            try
            {
                client.Connect(host, port); // подключение клиента
                stream = client.GetStream(); // получаем поток отправки и получения данных

                if (client.Connected) // если подключение к серверу успешно
                {
                    messageTextBox.Enabled = true; // разрешаем вводить сообщения для отправки
                    sendButton.Enabled = true; // разрешаем отправлять сообщения серверу
                    logoutButton.Enabled = true; // делаем активной кнопку выхода из чата

                    userNameTextBox.Enabled = false;
                    loginButton.Enabled = false;

                    // Отправляем имя
                    byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(userName);
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                    // Запускаем новый поток для получения данных
                    receiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveMessage));
                    receiveThread.Start(); // запускаем поток
                    chatTextBox.Text += "Добро пожаловать, " + userName + "\r\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    chatTextBox.Text += "Отсутствует подключение к серверу!\r\n";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                Disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    // Отправка данных
    private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string message = messageTextBox.Text;
        byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        chatTextBox.Text += string.Format($"Вы: {message}\r\n");
        messageTextBox.Text = "";
    }

    // Получение данных
    private void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[128]; // буфер для получаемых данных
                StringBuilder getString = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    getString.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (stream.DataAvailable);


                //chatTextBox.Invoke(
                //    (ThreadStart)delegate ()
                //    {
                //        chatTextBox.Text += string.Format($"{getString.ToString()}\r\n");
                //    });
                chatTextBox.Text += string.Format($"{getString.ToString()}\r\n");
            }
            catch
            {
                chatTextBox.Invoke(
                    (ThreadStart)delegate ()
                    {
                        chatTextBox.Text += string.Format("Подключение прервано!");
                    });
                //chatTextBox.Text += string.Format("Подключение прервано!");
                Disconnect();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Disconnect()
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close();
        if (client != null)
            client.Close();
    }

    private void logoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        receiveThread.Abort();
        receiveThread.Join(500);

        Disconnect();

        userNameTextBox.Enabled = true;
        loginButton.Enabled = true;

        messageTextBox.Enabled = false;
        sendButton.Enabled = false;
        logoutButton.Enabled = false;

    }
}
}
```

Сервер:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Server
{
public class ClientObject
{
    internal string Id { get; private set; }
    internal NetworkStream Stream { get; set; }
    string userName;
    TcpClient client;
    ServerObject server; // объект сервера

    public ClientObject(TcpClient tcpClient, ServerObject serverObject)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        client = tcpClient;
        server = serverObject;
        server.AddConnection(this);
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        try
        {
            Stream = client.GetStream();
            // Получаем имя пользователя
            userName = GetMessage();
            string message = userName + " вошел в чат.";
            // Рассылаем сообщение о входе в чат всем подключенным пользователям
            server.BroadcastMessage(message, Id);
            Console.WriteLine(message);

            // В бесконечном цикле получаем данные от пользователя
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    message = GetMessage();
                    message = string.Format($"{userName}: {message}");
                    server.BroadcastMessage(message, Id);
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                }
                catch
                {
                    message = userName + " покинул чат.";
                    server.BroadcastMessage(message, Id);
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Удаляем пользователя из списка подключенных пользователей и закрываем поток с соединением
            server.RemoveConnection(Id);
            Close();
        }
    }

    internal string GetMessage()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[128];
        StringBuilder getString = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = 0;
        do
        {
            bytes = Stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            getString.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
        }
        while (Stream.DataAvailable);

        return getString.ToString();
    }

    internal void Close()
    {
        if (Stream != null)
            Stream.Close(); // закрываем поток
        if (client != null)
            client.Close(); // закрываем соединение
    }
}

public class ServerObject
{
    TcpListener listener;
    List<ClientObject> clients = new List<ClientObject>();

    // Добавляем пользователя в список подключенных пользователей
    internal void AddConnection(ClientObject clientObject)
    {
        clients.Add(clientObject);
    }

    // Отправляем сообщение всем пользователям, кроме отправителя
    internal void BroadcastMessage(string message, string id)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
        for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
        {
            if (clients[i].Id != id)
            {
                clients[i].Stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    // Удаляем пользователя из списка подключенных пользователей
    internal void RemoveConnection(string id)
    {
        ClientObject client = clients.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
        if (client != null)
            clients.Remove(client);
    }

    public void Listen()
    {
        try
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
            listener.Start(); // запуск прослушивания входящих запросов
            Console.WriteLine("Ожидание подключений...");

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                ClientObject clientObject = new ClientObject(tcpClient, this);
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clientObject.Process));
                clientThread.Start(); // старт потока
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            Disconnect();
        }
    }

    internal void Disconnect()
    {
        listener.Stop(); // отсанавливаем сервер

        for (int i = 0; i < clients.Count; i++)
        {
            clients[i].Close();
        }
    }


}

class Program
{
    static ServerObject server;
    static Thread listenerThread;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            server = new ServerObject();
            listenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(server.Listen));
            listenerThread.Start(); // старт потока
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
            server.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на кнопку выход сервер начинает спамить пустыми сообщениями от клиента, как будто каждую секунду клиент по 10 раз отправляет сообщение без текста, хотя клиент отключен. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 3):

Вот этот код:

```
do
{
    bytes = Stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    getString.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
}
while (Stream.DataAvailable);
```

категорически неверен.

Нельзя предполагать, что одно сообщение от клиента придёт одним куском. Сообщения могут быть и будут фрагментированы, ведь TCP — потоковый формат. Поэтому чтение до исчерпания данных в потоке просто неверно, хвост данных может прийти позже.

Кроме того, этот метод предполагает, что обязательно придут данные. Если данные не пришли (например, клиент больше ничего не посылает), этот метод всё равно что-то вернёт.

Кроме того, этот метод пытается интерпретировать частичные данные как строку в UTF-16. Если будет прислано нечётное количество байт (или суррогатная пара окажется разрезанной), это приведёт к исключению.

---

Обычно используется следующий трюк: к сообщению приписывается его длина, и код читает байты до тех пор, пока не считает нужное количество байт. Когда все байты считаны, можно приступать к декодированию сообщения.

Comment: Похожие вопросы уже были, например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/648897/10105

Comment: А можно небольшой пример формирования потока с информацией о длине сообщения и его обработка.

Comment: @camtasia: Вроде пробегал пару раз, сейчас поищу...

Comment: @camtasia: Вот тут например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/659066/10105. Вам нужен `SendAsync` для отправки, и внутренняя часть вечного цикла (без `RaiseEventMessegaReceive`) для приёма.

Answer (score 1):

Обрати внимание на свой метод: GetMessage().
В нём ты в любом случае возвращаешь строку, даже если поток был пустой.
Тебе необходимо проверять на сервере содержимое возвращаемого сообщения и в самом методе немного изменить логику приёма сообщений.