# Передача файлов с использованием TCP Socket - C#

Tags: c#, .net, сокет, tcp

Доброго времени суток. Возникла проблема при попытке передать файл с помощью сокетов. Сервер обрабатывает не все отправленные на него данные (например из 26 кб получает 16 кб). Заметил один непонятный момент: если между методом socket.Receive() и записью в MemoryStream добавить строчку кода, например записи данных в лог файл (File.AppendAllText("Log.log", string.Format("Received={0}\r\n", received)), то все работает нормально. Подскажите что я делаю не так? Заранее спасибо

Код сервера:

```
namespace TCPServer {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);

                Socket listenSoc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                listenSoc.Bind(endPoint);
                listenSoc.Listen(10);
                Console.WriteLine("Server is running...");

                int bytes = 0;
                const int bufferSize = 8192;
                while (true) {
                    Socket handler = listenSoc.Accept();

                    NetFile file;
                    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                        do {
                            int received = handler.Receive(buffer);
                            //File.AppendAllText("Log.log", string.Format("Received={0}\r\n", received));
                            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, received);
                            bytes += received;
                        }
                        while (handler.Available > 0);
                        file = new NetFile(memStream.ToArray());
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Size of received data: " + bytes.ToString() + " bytes");

                    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(file.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
                        stream.Write(file.Data, 0, file.Data.Length);
                    }

                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();

                    bytes = 0;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception error) {
                Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код клиента:

```
namespace TcpClient {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            try {
                IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8080);

                Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                socket.Connect(endPoint);
                Console.WriteLine("Client connected");

                Console.WriteLine("Sending file...");
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("c:\\1.sql", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
                    byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
                    int length = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    NetFile file = new NetFile();
                    file.FileName = Path.GetFileName(stream.Name);
                    file.Data = data;

                    byte[] to = file.ToArray();
                    socket.Send(to);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("File sended");

                socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                socket.Close();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            catch (Exception error) {
                Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс с информацией об отправляемом файле:

```
namespace ExchangeEngine.Net {

    [Serializable]
    public class NetFile {
        private byte[] _data;

        public NetFile() { }

        public NetFile(byte[] data) {
            NetFile file = FromArray(data);
            FileName = file.FileName;
            Data = file.Data;
        }

        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public byte[] Data {
            get {
                return _data;
            }
            set {
                _data = value;
                Checksum = GetMD5Hash(_data);
            }
        }

        public string Checksum { get; set; }

        public static string GetMD5Hash(byte[] source) {
            StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder();
            using (MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create()) {
                byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(source);
                for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++) {
                    hash.Append(data[index].ToString("x2"));
                }

                return hash.ToString();
            }
        }

        public byte[] ToArray() {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, this);

                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static NetFile FromArray(byte[] data) {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data)) {
                stream.Position = 0;
                return (NetFile)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос не читал, вангую, что вы предполагаете, будто бы посланное одним куском придёт тоже одним куском.

Comment: @VladD Почему одним куском? handler.Receive() в цикле при условии что handler.Available > 0

Comment: Ну вот, а почему не может сначала прийти один кусок, а другой через минуту? Цикл прочитает первый кусок, увидит, что пока больше ничего нет, и благополучно завершится.

Comment: @VladD Я писал код основываясь из примеров на сайте MSDN и других крупных ресурсов. Каким образом я могу дождаться получения всей информации?

Comment: Например, передавайте в начале длину файла, и ждите, пока придёт столько байт, сколько нужно.

Comment: Вот например: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html, для вашего случая https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html

Comment: @VladD Огромное спасибо

Comment: Отпишитесь в комментариях, заработало ли. // Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD Все работает

Comment: Отлично, тогда оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как показало расследование в комментариях, виноват код

```cs
do {
    int received = handler.Receive(buffer);
    //File.AppendAllText("Log.log", string.Format("Received={0}\r\n", received));
    memStream.Write(buffer, 0, received);
    bytes += received;
}
while (handler.Available > 0);
```

Дело в том, что из-за сетевых задержек часть данных может быть ещё в пути, когда начало уже вычитано. Сокет работает в потоковом, а не блочном режиме, и не знает, что будут ещё доставлены данные. Поэтому использовать `Available` для распознавания конца передачи нецелесообразно.

Самое простое и практичное решение — перед передачей информации передавать её *длину*. На читающей стороне принимать сначала длину, а потом читать до тех пор, пока не прочитается нужное количество байт.

Литература по теме: [Message Framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) и вообще [TCP/IP .NET Sockets FAQ](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html) в блоге Стивена Клири.

---

На всякий случай код. На стороне получателя:

```cs
async Task<byte[]> ReadBytes(int howmuch)
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[howmuch];
    int readPos = 0;
    while (readPos < howmuch)
    {
        var actuallyRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, readPos, howmuch - readPos);
        if (actuallyRead == 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException();
        readPos += actuallyRead;
    }
    return buf;
}

async Task<int> ReadInt()
{
    byte[] bytes = await ReadBytes(sizeof(int));
    return IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0));
}

async Task<byte[]> ReadFileWithLengthPrefix()
{
    int length = await ReadInt();
    byte[] bytes = ReadBytes(length);
    return bytes;
}
```

На стороне отправителя:

```cs
async Task SendBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, bytes.Length);
}

async Task SendInt(int n)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(n));
    await SendBytes(bytes);
}

async Task SendFileWithLengthPrefix(byte[] content)
{
    await SendInt(content.Length);
    await SendBytes(content);
}
```

Comment: Очень хочется увидеть результат. Везде примерно такой ответ, а по факту, как это делается, нету(

Comment: @ТаксистМолодой: Дописал код приёма и передачи. Остальную часть сервера/клиента уж допишите сами, там в любом случае всё просто.