# Как прочесть полностью ответ IMAP-сервера произвольной длины?

Tags: c#, сокет, ssl, imap, .net-standard

Изменю вопрос, основываясь на ответе пользователя Zergatul: как однозначно определить конец сообщения IMAP-сервера? После нескольких часов мучений с Гуглом я почти ничего не нашёл. Есть идея передавать условие завершения функции в качестве предиката, однако такое решение очень не гибкое.

```
static TcpClient tcp;
static SslStream ssl;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    tcp = new TcpClient("imap.gmail.com", 993);
    ssl = new SslStream(tcp.GetStream());
    ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("imap.gmail.com");

    ReceiveResponse("");
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = Console.ReadLine();
            if (query == "exit") break;
            Console.WriteLine(ReceiveResponse(query + "\r\n"));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(ReceiveResponse("$ LOGOUT\r\n"));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static string ReceiveResponse(string query)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        if (query != "")
        {
            if (tcp.Connected)
            {
                byte[] dummy = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(query);
                ssl.Write(dummy, 0, dummy.Length);
            }
        } else {
            throw new ApplicationException("tcp connection failure");
        }
    }
    ssl.Flush();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    List<byte> response = new List<byte>();
    while (true) // ваш метод, который определит полный ответ
    {
        int bytesRead = ssl.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
        if (bytesRead == 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException("err");
        string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Replace("\0", "");
        sb.Append(str);
        if (str.Contains("$ OK")) break;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы не должны использовать `IsAvailable` вовсе. Это свойство практически бесполезно.

Вы должны точно знать, сколько байт вам нужно прочитать. Если количество байт известно, то чтение производится таким циклом:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[N];
int readSoFar = 0;
while (readSoFar < buffer.Length)
{
    int bytesRead = ssl.Read(buffer, readSoFar, buffer.Length - readSoFar);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
        throw new EndOfStreamException();
    readSoFar += bytesRead;
}
```

Поскольку TCP — потоковый протокол, вы *не можете* узнать, где заканчивается сообщение, не подглядывая в его структуру, самый простой метод — передавать перед сообщением его длину.

---

Практически дубликат: [Передача файлов с использованием TCP Socket - C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/648960/10105).

Полезная статья по теме: [TCP/IP .NET Sockets FAQ / Message Framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html).

Comment: А как мне заранее узнать длину сообщения? Разве это возможно?

Comment: Ваш код падает на второй итерации при вызове ssl.Read(). Размер буфера установил в 1 кБ.

Comment: @VUser: Что означает «падает» Исключение? Какое? И число `N` равно не размеру буфера, а размеру сообщения. То есть код будет крутиться в цикле, пока не прочитает `N` байт.

Comment: @VUser: Ну сервер передаёт сообщения в каком-то формате.Посмотрите в RFC, какой формат IMAP-сообщений. Соответственно поймёте, где и когда заканчивать чтение.

Comment: @VUser: Согласно [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-2.2), данные от сервера идут либо как строка (тогда вам нужно читать до CRLF), либо как бинарные данные известной длины. Соответственно вам нужны две процедуры: прочитать кусок бинарных данных известной длины (это в моём коде есть), и прочитать по байтам до CRLF (аналогично).

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя так просто считывать данные от сервера. В каждом прикладном протоколе есть механизмы для определения конца ответа. Вы должны продолжать считывать данные, пока не увидите, что считали полное сообщение.

Например, для FTP ответы от сервера выглядят так:

```
220 Service Ready\r\n
```

Или

```
220-Service Ready\r\n
220-Microsoft FTP Server\r\n
220\r\n
```

Заранее длина ответа не передается, вы должны в цикле считывать данные со стрима, приблизительно так:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
List<byte> response = new List<byte>();
while (!IsFullMessageReceived(response)) // ваш метод, который определит полный ответ
{
    int bytesRead = ssl.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
        throw new EndOfStreamException();
    response.AddRange(buffer.Take(bytesRead));
}
// вот здесь вы начинаете обрабатывать сообщение
```

Я не знаю, как устроены ответы IMAP протокола, в случае FTP/SMTP можете посмотреть пример моего кода: https://github.com/Zergatul/ZergatulLib/blob/master/Zergatul/Network/ControlStreamReader.cs#L79

Здесь я считываю байты со стрима, и превращаю их в строку. Как только целая строка прочитана, идет проверка на многострочный ответ (со знаком "-" после кода ответа). Если это многострочный ответ, строки считываются дальше, пока не будет найдена строка с кодом без "-". Это сигнализирует конец ответа.
Если ответ однострочный, значит возвращаем его.

Comment: И все же, может, кто-нибудь может подсказать признак конца сообщения? Все, что я нагуглил, это ответы сервера BAD, OK, NO. Но ведь это довольно часто встречающиеся в сообщениях слова, и нельзя обрывать сообщение, опираясь ни их поиск. Прошу помочь, т.к. с английским туговато, а время поджимает.

Comment: @VUser я пытался беглым взглядом найти в RFC место, где об этом написано, но там видимо немного сложно. Есть ведь русский перевод вот здесь: http://rfc.com.ru/rfc2060.htm Если позже будет время, может посмотрю и сам

Comment: @VUser я вижу вы отрезаете `\0` в строке, возможно `\0` и есть конец ответа?

Comment: нуль-символы - это незаполненные байты в массиве байтов. При преобразовании массива байтов в строку `default(byte)` становится `default(char)`.

Comment: Видимо, придётся перебрать все ответы сервера, их всего не так уж много, если, возможно, не лезть в глубокие дебри протокола. Как-то так: `if (str.Contains("$ OK") || str.Contains("$ NO") || str.Contains("Gimap") || str.Contains("* BAD")) break;`. и вместо доллара вставить потом нужный тег.